# preg_match() is working on php70.14(ubuntu) but not on php5.3.26 (windows 2008)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to match information from file but when I try to regex it using `preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]{4}$/")` I can match single line but not when I am reading from the file directly. my code as follows:

```
<?php

$line = "23146";
$line = str_replace("\n", "", $line);
if(preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]{4}$/", $line, $matches)) { // Matching the PO No.
    print_r($matches);
}

// Following don't work on PHP 5.3.26

$file = fopen("meaw.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file");

while(!feof($file)) {

    $line = fgets($file);
    if(preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]{4}$/", $line, $matches)) { // Matching the PO No.
        print_r($matches);
    }

}

fclose($file);
echo "\nFile Closed";


?>
```

and my file is this [meaw.txt](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cvo-random/meaw.txt)

My problem is that this code works file when I am running it on ubuntu PHP7. But when I am running this code on windows2008 php5.3.26 it prints the following

> Array
>   (
>      [0] => 23146
>   )
>
> File Closed

But I am supposed to get

> Array (
>       [0] => 23146 ) Array (
>       [0] => 63144 ) Array (
>       [0] => 63140 ) Array (
>       [0] => 63201 ) Array (
>       [0] => 63148 ) Array (
>       [0] => 63201 ) Array (
>       [0] => 63148 ) Array (
>       [0] => 63201 ) Array (
>       [0] => 63148 ) Array (
>       [0] => 63201 ) Array (
>       [0] => 63140 ) Array (
>       [0] => 63148 )
>
> File Closed

Can some one please tell me why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: You might need to trim content too.

Comment: Did you try to var_dump $line after you get it?

Comment: @E_p I just realized that on windows new line is "\r\n" I forgot about that since I rarely do anything on windows. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Windows reads new line as **"\r\n"** but unix reads it differently. All I had to do was add the following inside the while loop

```
$line = str_replace("\r\n", "", $line);
```

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php, `PHP_EOL`.